# BlackBerry 10 NFC Support

Tags: nfc, blackberry-10

I have to develop an application for BB 10 device which sends data via NFC to an USB NFC reader attached to the PC. I am new with BB 10 device and don't know what are the supported card types and data protocols. Please share the BB 10 device NFC capabilities if any one have. I have the following doubts regarding BB 10 NFC architecture.
   What are the supported card types (ISO 14443-4, Mifare, Desfire, ...) that can be read using a BB 10 device?

What are the supported Pear to Pear data exchange (SNEP, LLCP,...) protocols?

What are the supported Card emulation (ISO 14443-4, Mifare, ...) Modes?

I prefer card emulation mode for exchanging data with the USB NFC Reader (ACS ACR 122 U). Is that is possible with the BB 10 alpha device.
 Thanks in advance.... 
Best regards 
Pranav

Comment: [Here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/NFC-Article-and-Code-Index/ta-p/1538775) are all the articles and code that RIM have published so far re: NFC on OS10 and prior OS's. Including how to develop with NFC for the OS10 NDK and WebWorks

Answer (score 2):

You may find useful the following link:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/tkb/articleprintpage/tkb-id/java_dev@tkb/article-id/656

Comment: That particular article is unfortunately 99% BlackBerry Java Dev. specific for upto OS7.  The OP needs similar for BlackBerry OS10

Comment: Trust me: about NFC and Card Emulation the situation is unchanged.

Comment: Can you provide a link to encourage my trust in you?

Comment: No, I cannot. I'm sorry. The unique link I have is: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/NFC-on-BlackBerry-10-Reading-and-Writing-Tags-using-native-APIs/ta-p/1721887 other information I have are not 'internet based'

Answer (score 0):

BlackBerry 10 has excellent support for NFC. I would start by [taking at the look at the documentation](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_comm/nfc/):

Also, there is a 6 part series of articles on the BlackBerry Developer Blog which goes through all the main aspects of developing an NFC app. [The first part is here.](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2013/09/porting-blackberry-java-nfc-applications-to-blackberry-10-part-1-reading-nfc-tags/)

Specifically you probably want to take a look at [part 5 which talks about virtual card emulation](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2013/10/porting-blackberry-java-nfc-applications-to-blackberry-10-part-5-virtual-tag-and-card-emulation/)